# Are the values in android app preferences saved automatically?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create preferences for an experimental app for android. However I can get the preferences to work.

The preference that I want to use determine the display langue and use this function to retrieve it:

```
private String selectLang()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String lang = preferences.getString("lang", "n/a");
    return lang;
}
```

Then inside onCreate method for the ListActivity I use this code to display the right language:

```
String lang =  selectLang();
String title = (lang == "english") ? "English" : "Arabic";
```

title is a column in the database. The code does not seem to work and I get Arabic no matter what. I used this code just to know the value of lang:

```
Toast.makeText(this, lang, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and I get "english" but the English language does not display.

Here is is my XML for the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="lang">
    <item>Arabic</item>
    <item>English</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="langValues">
    <item>arabic</item>
    <item>english</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

I have read in number of answers here on SO that I should use SharedPreference editor but I could not get a full working example of that.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This: `lang == "english"` should be `lang.equals("english")`.

Compare strings (as any other object) using `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`. The `==` operator compares object references, not content of objects, so your check always evaluated as false.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew there is something with that line of code which why I included it. Coming from PHP background it is really not easy to grasp fully the OOP design and compiled languages such as Java.

Comment: Java is my favorite language, but I think (and I'm not the only one) that this is the most confusing syntax of Java. There are about 5 or more questions per day which has this issue exactly as their root problem...

Comment: Referring to your initial question: you would still need to use the preferences editor and commit, if you want to change and save the values, they don't store automatically: SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); editor.commit();

Comment: They actually did store automatically. I tried the code that I submitted in the question and it worked without using editor class.